# Take names associated with x values from one data frame, and use them to populate a 'names' column in a second data frame (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one data frame with columns of x and y values (xy_dat_df), and another dataframe that provides names for certain ranges of x (name_ranges_df), in the form of an x value, a width value and a name.  I want to add a column to xy_dat_df called names which populates with names as per name_ranges_df where the x values of xy_dat_df are within the range defined by the x value in name_ranges_df, plus or minus the width value from name_ranges_df.

At the moment I'm doing this by calling lapply on the names from name_ranges_df, and assigning names for xy_dat_df using a <<- assignment.  It seems like a pretty ugly way to do it, but I'm struggling to think of a better way.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Below is a minimal working example of what I'm trying to do.  This does actually work, but I think there must be a better way.

```
name_ranges_df <- data.frame(x = c(4, 6, 12, 15, 18), width = c(1.2,0.8,0.7,0.65,1.0), name = c("a","b","c","d","e"))
xy_dat_df <- data.frame(x = seq(1,20, by = 0.01))
xy_dat_df$y <- sin(xy_dat_df$x)+runif(nrow(xy_dat_df2),min=0, max=1)
lapply(name_ranges_df$name, function(n){
  target.x <- name_ranges_df$x[name_ranges_df$name==n]
  target.width <- name_ranges_df$width[name_ranges_df$name==n]
  xy_dat_df$name[xy_dat_df$x>target.x-target.width & xy_dat_df$x<target.x+target.width] <<- n
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add columns to `name_ranges_df` that reflect the min/max, or lower and upper bounds of the range into which `x` must fall, you can then use non-equi join in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(name_ranges_df)
setDT(xy_dat_df)

# add min_x and max_x columns to name_ranges_df
name_ranges_df[, `:=`(min_x = x-width, max_x=x+width)]

# join the tables
name_ranges_df[, -c(1:2)][xy_dat_df, on=.(min_x<x, max_x>x)]
```

you can also use `join_by()` from `dplyr()`

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(
  xy_dat_df,
  name_ranges_df %>% mutate(min_x = x-width, max_x=x+width),
  by=join_by(x>min_x, x<max_x)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work.  There's a couple of things here that I'm not clear on though.  Is ':=' a function? Is that a standard syntax, or something from the data.table package?
And what about the on=. part of the second statement? I haven't seen that before either.

Comment: you modify/generate columns in data.table in-place using the `:=` operator, as in `dt[,z:=x+y]`.  If you want to modify/generate multiple columns in-place in one statement, you can use as I did (i.e. `dt[, ``:=``(z1=x+y, z2=x-y, z3=x*y)]`)

Comment: Cool, I'm learning something new.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `on` clause is similar to `by` in `merge` or in `dplyr::inner_join()`

Comment: I tend to default to data.table because of its speed, but note that you can also do this type of non-equi join using `dplyr::join_by()` - I've added an example

Comment: Would it be quicker to convert my data frames to data tables, apply the join, and convert back to data frames (for downstream applications) or to join using dplyr?  My actual data consists of ~120000 rows, and I'm applying this whole process over quite a few data sets, so computational efficiency is going to make a difference.

Comment: you may find data.table is faster, but hard to say with just this information. greater efficiency might lie in how you are "applying this whole process over quite a few data sets", rather than choosing between dplyr/data.table.. 120,000 rows does not sound very large, but again, not easy to answer with just this information

Comment: Ok so I have a problem.  When I apply this approach to the minimal example data, it works fine.  But when I apply it to my actual data, the result of the join somehow ends up with extra rows:
> nrow(fid_df)
[1] 120083
> nrow(pdf_df[,c(7, 14:15)][fid_df, on=.(min_x<rt, max_x>rt)])
[1] 120120
>

Comment: that suggests to me that one of the x values can fall in more than one range (min to max interval), which is only possible if the ranges overlap.  Do you have ranges that overlap?

Comment: Yes I was thinking that was probably the problem too.  Yes, ranges will overlap.  I wonder if some conditional logic can be incorporated into the assigning of names so that points closest to the center of their range will be prioritised?

Comment: just use a filter after the join to drop the duplicate that is further from the center

Comment: I went with creating a function to adjust the x_min and x_max for overlapping names before applying the join, which works fine.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

With {powerjoin} (dev version) you might do:

```
# remotes::install_github("moodymudskipper/powerjoin")
powerjoin::power_left_join(
  xy_dat_df, 
  name_ranges_df, 
  by = ~ .x$x > .y$x - .y$width & .x$x < .y$x + .y$width
)
```

Comment: this is a nice addition, because it shows an alternative where the join condition can be dynamically created within the join clause; neither `data.table` or `join_by()` can do this (currently).

Comment: Thanks, there is also the fuzzyjoin package that my package took code from, but the syntax is quite complex and I solved a few bugs on the way